# Angular2 app how to draw square [input] times?

Tags: angular, canvas, typescript, draw

I want to draw [input] squares in some container using Angular2.
Could you give me simple example how to do it? Prefer using canvas.

So far I change webpack starter to angular:

This is **square.component.template.html**:

```
<h1>My component</h1>
<p>first paragraph</p>
<div class="container">
<form (ngSubmit)="draw(counter.value)" autocomplete="off">

    <input [value]="counter.value" (input)="counter.value = $event.target.value" placeholder="Number of squares" autofocus>

    <button md-raised-button color="primary">Submit Value</button>
</form>
<canvas width="350" height="800"></canvas>
```

This is **square.component.ts**:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';


@Component({
  selector: 'square',
  templateUrl: './square.component.template.html'
})
export class DetailComponent {
   // Set our default values
   counter = { value: '' };
   constructor() {

}

 ngOnInit() {
   console.log('hello `Detail` component');
 }

draw(value: number) {
console.log('counter', value);
for (var i = 0; i < value; i++) {
  var canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
  var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

  var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF';
  var color = '#';
  for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
  }

  context.fillStyle = color;
  context.fillRect(10, 10, 100, 50);
}
this.counter.value = 0;
}
```

It draws a square but only in 1 place. What is more, if i type value > 50 browser crashes ;/ I am beginner in a2. Can you help me?

Comment: post edited , take a look

Answer (score 0):

You are giving the same position to all boxes so they will print in one place. For that you can try this

```
 draw(value: number) {
  console.log('counter', value);
  var canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
  var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
  var topPos = 10;
  for (var i = 0; i < value; i++) {
    var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF';
    var color = '#';
    for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
    }

  context.fillStyle = color;
  context.fillRect(10, topPos , 100, 50);
  topPos = topPos + 55
 }
this.counter.value = 0;
}
```

Comment: ok I managed to do it. What if I want now to draw more squares than canvas width/height can hold? How can I implement mechanism of scroll here if canvas height (Y position of square reach the 800px) has been reached?